# Why is training take so long on my GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

## Details:

**GPU**: GTX 1080

**Training**: ~1.1 Million images belonging to 10 classes

**Validation**: ~150 Thousand images belonging to 10 classes

**Time per Epoch**: ~10 hours

I've setup CUDA, cuDNN and Tensorflow( Tensorflow GPU as well).

I don't think my model is that complicated that is takes 10 hours per epoch. I even checked if my GPU was the problem but it wasn't.

Is the training time due to the Fully connected layers?

## My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same", strides=2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer=opt,
          metrics=['accuracy']
          )
```

Because there is a lot of data I used the ImageDataGenerator.

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator(
 horizontal_flip=True
)

train_gen = gen.flow_from_directory(
        'train/',
        target_size=(512, 512),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode="categorical"
)

valid_gen = gen.flow_from_directory(
        'validation/',
        target_size=(512, 512),
        batch_size=5,
        class_mode="categorical"
)
```

Comment: I voted to move this to stack overflow, but really it belongs on the data science stack exchange, IMO

Comment: generic_user: "data science" may use "machine learning", but not all "machine learning" is for "data science". (ML is just another tool, tensorflow just another library; ML might soon (if not already) be used even for the mundane tasks such as managing user preference property files.)

Comment: see also related (tl;dr: verify actually running on gpu, look at gpu stats that tf can provide) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527492/tensorflow-how-to-verify-that-it-is-running-on-gpu  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow

Comment: I've tried that approach and it states that my current GPU is being used. In order to confirm I also used **nvidia-smi** to check the GPU utilization and it kinda fluctuates between 85%-99%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's about expected. If you divide the number of seconds by the number of images you processed, you get 33 milliseconds per image, which seems about right for such a small network. Larger networks usually take in the ballpark of 50 to 200 milliseconds per image.

Yes, a large dense layer is likely to hurt your performance, since that's a huge matrix (256 by 4096) and a large matrix multiplication to go along with it every time you run the network.

Comment: What would you suggest to improve performance?

Comment: 1: increase batch size to 32 or 64. 2: shrink the size of FC layer to maybe 1024 or 2048 units and see if it helps. 3: Early stopping. It's possible that your network has converged or starts overfitting before you finish your first epoch, in which case you should train less.

Comment: Should I reduce the steps per epoch?

Comment: @shimao what did you mean by "train less"? Do you mean use less data?

Answer (score 3):

As shimao said, that's about what you'd expect. Despite not having many layers, an input size of 512x512 is a large image to be convolving over. The large computation time is likely more due to convolving 64 filters over the large image, instead of the fully connected layers.

The network you've put together has a funny information bottleneck in it though. You start off with 64 filters on the original sized image, only decreasing as your image size reduces. As the image passes through your network, the features you're learning become more and more abstracted and complex. Your Conv2D(32, (3, 3)) layer essentially limits the network to learning a 128x128 map of 32 features.

Most network architectures double the number of features every time they pool, and most recent imagenet architectures actually ditch the fully connected layers in favour of an average pool over the final feature map, and basically perform logistic regression on the output of that pool.

Try starting off with fewer filters, say 16 in your first convolution layer, doubling each time you stride or pool. Do this a few more times than you are, to increase receptive field and decrease feature map size. Do this down to 64x64 or 32x32, which would be 128 or 256 filters. You can use Keras' Global Avg or Max pooling to eliminate fully connected layers as well. That should about double the speed of the network, and I would expect an increase in accuracy at the same time.

Comment: Well, the network architecture is based on a research paper I was trying to reproduce.http://www.lirmm.fr/%7Echaumont/publications/WIFS-2016_TUAMA_COMBY_CHAUMONT_Camera_Model_Identification_With_CNN.pdf